# Android Studio folders and Version Control for small projects (SVN)

Tags: android, android-studio, svn

I'm just one person working on some relatively small projects (20 source files, 20 layouts, a couple dozen files as image and raw resources). Not using the unit testing directories for anything.

I have a Subversion / SVN server running on my local NAS and it works just fine for a web project I have (couple hundred files, small number of directories). I want to use SVN with Android Studio as well. (Considered GIT, but I prefer the structural model of SVN because I think it fits the development "team" (just me) size better and the structure matches what I've used in the past.)

My question is, what is the minimum amount that I need to add to version control in order to pull out a complete buildable directory later? The project directory has a couple thousand files in it, and I've created only 40-60 of those.

I've given the IDE's VCS->Import into Version Control->Import into Subversion a shot, but it seems that method is "dumb" in that it takes **everything**. The tutorials I've seen suggest that this really isn't needed or correct.

Here's what I *think* is correct:

```
Project
+.gradle (ignore)
+.idea (ignore)
+app
 +build (ignore)
 +libs (VCS)
 +src
  +androidTest (ignore)
  +main (VCS)
  +test (ignore)
 +build (ignore)
 +gradle (VCS)
gradlew (VCS)
gradlew.bat (VCS)
build.gradle (VCS)
settings.gradle (VCS)
Project.iml (VCS)
gradle.properties (VCS)
local.properties (ignore)
```

Now, given that the project exists, what's the best way to get it **in** to SVN? And which directories should be ignored for content, but stored as folders only? I can't create ignore rules until I've checked out the main directory, so it kind of seems like manually creating the needed directories in SVN first, all empty, then checking them out to a new location, then copying over the project, then command line adding just the source and resource and top level gradle stuff is the cleanest way to do it. Using the built in Android Studio method, importing everything, then deleting the content from the repository with a third party tool seems pretty awful.

```
Android Studio 2.2
Server SVN 1.9.4 on Synology NAS
Clients Android Studio / SVN command line 1.9.4 / SVNBreeze /TortoiseSVN
```

Comment: `seems like manually creating the needed directories in SVN first` - i would do the same.